# Blink text in a c:out (jsp / jstl)

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am attempting to blink the text in the following c:out line

```
<td bgcolor="green" align="center" > <font color="white"> <b> <c:out value="${row.ready}"/> </b> </font> </td>
```

I appreciate that using `<blink>` is not advised and so I tried some of the various 'alternatives' including -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
      $('blink').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle();
      });
    }, 250);
</script>
<blink>Text to blink here</blink>
```

But this does not work (in Firefox) in the c:out line, though Eclipse seems to accept `<blink>`

Is there an alternative which does not require 50 lines of code and altering CSS's?

Regards
Active

Comment: Use `<span class="blink">` instead of `<blink>`, and then `$('.blink').each( ...`

Comment: Thanks Jozef, apologies (as a newbie) could you expand your reply and show it in my complete c:out line, I am having trouble with syntax and placement

Comment: Basically just wrap your `<c:out ... />` tag into `<span class="blink">`. The `<c:out>` tag is processed server-side (i.e. browser has no knowledge about it), it prints the content of the variable referenced in the `value` attribute. If you somehow want to format that content, you have to wrap it (e.g. in a `<span>` tag).

Comment: Also, **do not** use the `<font>` tag, format your output using [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Comment: Thanks again but I added wrapped c:out in span class="blink" but the text is not blinking

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/j9xffqvz/ - it's "blinking", i.e. disappearing and reappearing. The real blinking would play with the text/background color (e.g. by adding/removing classes).

Comment: Thanks again, but using simple text between the span tags does indeed blink, but when I <span id="blink"> <c:out value="${row.ready}"/> </span> the row.ready value displays but does not blink. My wrapping syntax may be wrong.

Comment: Inspect the final HTML, post it here if possible.